# Compiling on MIPS Android missing machine/_types.h

Tags: android, gcc, mips

I am trying to build some small test programs for running on a mips board.

While trying to compile I am getting this error.

```
EXTRALDFLAGS=-Wall -g3 -static -pthread  -Dpthread_yield=sched_yield
TOOL_PREFIX=/crux/shared/mips-android/bin/mipsel-linux-android- make -f gcc-makefile 
clean all
echo "Cleaning...." 
Cleaning....
rm -f dining.o
rm -f test
/crux/shared/mips-android/bin/mipsel-linux-android-gcc -g    -c dining.c -o dining.o
In file included from /crux/mips-android/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/stdint.h:32:0,
             from /crux/mips-android/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6.x
google/include/stdint.h:3,
             from /crux/mips-android/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6.x
google/include-fixed/sys/types.h:43,
from /crux/mips-android/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/sys/time.h:32,
enter code herefrom /crux/mips-android/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/time.h:32,
             from /crux/mips-android/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/pthread.h:31,
             from dining.c:1: 
/crux/mips-android/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/sys/_types.h:40:28: fatal error:
machine/_types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [dining.o] Error 1
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, first time on here

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Is it "why is this file missing?", or "why is this include needed?" or "should I use a different sys image?".  Please try to rephrase.

Comment: I know the file machine/_type.h is needed but I have no idea where or how to get this file. It doesn't seem to be in the MIPs android source.